# I am trying to make my extension change background-color of every event containing certain word(or set of characters) in Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I am taking my first steps in JS, I know that I have a lot of reading ahead of me, but I am searching and trying to make this little thing work. Maybe I've chosen a bad example of a website for testing influence of chrome extensions, but maybe solving this problem will somehow enlighten me and help with future learning.

I want to change the background-color of google calendar events depending on words/set of characters they contain.
I tried using contains() selector which seemed to work on simplier websites (I could see the CSS applied in DevTools) but divs with events on Google Calendar stay untouched.

Can the script somehow be blocked by Google Calendar? Should I use some of the permissions listed on [developer.chrome.com/extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) ?

Sorry that I am not attaching any code at the moment, I don't have it with me, and I can't recreate it from the head. I wanted to post it in my free time, and at least get some new ideas.

I'll be grateful for any help!

Comment: I wonder if your contains() check is running before Google Calendar populates itself. If so, you can try either a mutationObserver or else a setInterval, and run your contains() check inside of them. To test, put your contains() check inside a setTimeout at 20 seconds or something.

Comment: Correct! I ve been thinking about it too but I was expecting bigger problems than that. To be honest I have never managed to use them before (its like 2 days of learning JS so far) and would have problems to use them properly, but your answer pointing at that solution mobilized me to do some research and try. Thanks! Have a great day!